# I want to edit a row in csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a python code handling csv files and I want to edit a row. The best way ive figured out is by deleting the row and adding the new edited row at the end. Im able to do everything other than deleting the row.

Here I am reading and creating a new edited row:

```
data = []

with open('followers.csv', 'r') as followersData:
    reader = csv.DictReader(followersData)

    for i in reader:
        if i['username'] == 'user1':
            data.append(i['username'])
            data.append(i['followers'])

    followers = data[1].split(sep='-')
    followers.append('user6')
    data[1] = '-'.join(followers)
```

After this I tried a few things but I can't delete the existing row or overwrite it. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the csv file and I want to edit the first row with information:

```
username,followers
user1,user2-user3-user4
user2,user1-user3-user4
user3,user1-user2-user4
```

Comment: what row do you want to edit in specific?

Comment: wait ill add them in the question

Comment: Can you share the content of followers.csv?

Comment: Easiest and safest way is to write all data (except the row to delete) to a newly created file and finally delete the original file and replace it with the new file by renaming.

Comment: Easiest thing is going to be to read the whole file into memory (as a list), modify the list, and then rewrite the entire file.

Comment: I know the easiest way to edit is to rewrite the file however I dont want to go that way in case of large data

Comment: If you have large data, use a database instead of a CSV.  A large part of the function of a database is to organize the data on disk in such a way that you can modify a subset of it without rewriting the entire thing.  CSVs don't have that; most in-place edits will require that you pay the I/O cost of rewriting the entire file anyway, it's just a question of whether you do it the easy way (all at once) or the hard way (in little chunks).

Comment: Do you want just to add user6 to every line?

Comment: I'll try that in my next project since im not well versed with databases or any format other than csv atm. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @funnydman no i only want to add it to a single row, user1 in this case

Comment: In any case you would have to rewrite the part of the file from the row to delete up to the end of the file.

Comment: @Samwise can you suggest any database for projects and where to learn it

Comment: I might suggest sqlite3 since it's built into Python and will let you learn SQL without the learning curve of setting up a database server.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet of code will add one follower to the person you specify

```
user_to_add = "user6"     # the new follower
user_to_add_to = "user1"   # the user we are adding the follower to
```

Entire code block:

```
import csv

# START:

# username,followers
# user1,user2-user3-user4
# user2,user1-user3-user4
# user3,user1-user2-user4

# END:

# username,followers
# user1,user2-user3-user4-user6
# user2,user1-user3-user4
# user3,user1-user2-user4

data = []

# "i only want to add it to a single row, user1 in this case"
# this section reads in data
with open('followers.csv', 'r') as followersData:
    reader = csv.DictReader(followersData)

    for i in reader:
        data.append(i)
    

user_to_add = "user6"     # the new follower
user_to_add_to = "user1"   # the user we are adding the follower to

# update the file
with open('followers.csv', 'w') as f:
    
    f.write("username,followers\n")  # add top line
    
    for row in data:
        
        if row["username"] == user_to_add_to:  # add new follower to the row
            old_followers = row["followers"]
            row["followers"] = f"{old_followers}-{user_to_add}"
        
        user = row["username"]
        followers = row["followers"]
        f.write(f"{user},{followers}\n")  # write row to file
```